# HTML not working inside of a PHP with Joomla

Tags: php, html, joomla

I am trying to use JFactory in Joomla to get a user's name. Then I want to use PHP to fetch their information from a MySQL table. However, I can't even use simple HTML. Using my example below, all HTML is ignored. How do I get it to recognize the HTML?
The website is: http://freecpr.org/index.php/training/first-aid-cpr-aed-online

My code is:

```html
{source}
$user = JFactory::getUser();

<?php
  if($user->id!=0){
    echo "{$user->name}";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "First Aid | CPR | AED: ";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Bloodborne Pathogens: ";
}
else{
    echo "Please Log In";
}
?>
{/source}

<hr />

<h1>Under Construction</h1>
```

Comment: Make sure that you adding the code correctly. Rather than trying to copy and paste it, try clicking the "Insert Code" button. Also, you do not need to use `$user = JFactory::getUser();` as Sourcerer creates this for you already

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{source}
<?php
$user = JFactory::getUser();

  if($user->id!=0){
    echo "{$user->name}";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "First Aid | CPR | AED: ";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Bloodborne Pathogens: ";
}
else{
    echo "Please Log In";
}
?>
{/source}

<hr />

<h1>Under Construction</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

html code should be with in {/source} so have

---

```
  <h1>Under Construction</h1>
```

{/source}